# if start date is set and date before expiration or end date is determined by the warranty period and prompt user

Tags: php, mysql, prompt

[image]

Image shows the start of the transaction which is the transaction date and end date is determined by the warranty period so if warranty period is five it will expire in 5  years how could[enter image description here][2] you do that in php

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Transaction Date - ".$trans_date = "2017-04-22";    
$warranty = 5;    
echo "Expiry Date - ".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($trans_date." +$warranty year"));
```

Comment: <?php

include ("../class/mysql_connection.php");

include ("../class/class_transaction.php");

$sql2=mysql_query("select * from tbl_transaction ") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

Echo "Transaction Period:".$ddate;
$warranty='$Warranty_Period';
echo "Expiry Date:".date("Y-D-M",strtotime($ddate."+$warranty year"));
}


?>

Comment: says that i have an undefined  variable ddate but it is the name of the table ... ; whats wrong with my code

Comment: $ddate what value is coming in ddate and $Warranty_Period

Comment: warranty = $Warranty_Period;    
$enddate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($ddate." +$warranty year")); now its working thanks gopi :)